# safe parameter bindings in sqlalchemy filter

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need to pass a partial raw sql query into sqlalchemy filter, like

```
s.query(account).filter("coordinate <@> point(%s,%s) < %s"%(lat,long,distance))
```

Yes, I'm trying to use earthdistance function in postgresql.

Of course, I could use PostGis and GeoAlchemy2, but I want to know the general solution to this kind of problems.

I know sqlalchemy can safely pass raw sql query .

```
result = db.engine.execute("select * coordinate <@> point(:lat,:long) < :distance",**params)
```

Is there any similar function that can be used to bind parameter of partial(?) sql query? I guess someone who implements custom sql function like func.ll_to_earth have used the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `.params()` on query. Try this:

```
query = s.query(account).filter(
    "coordinate <@> point(:lat, :long_) < :dist").params(
        lat=lat, long_=long_, dist=distance)
```

And [there is the documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.params) on it.

Note: I renamed your `long` param, because there is alread a `__builtin__` named `long` (long int) in python, it's good practice to not overwrite already used words for obvious reasons.